# Read and Generate New Enumber

Tags: c#

Hi i am new here i just want to ask question for this code.

i am making a condition on my new buttom that generate Enumber= Employee Number.

i have database but no data record yet. if i press my new buttom my sql statement will select he last record on my data but i don't have yet data so i am trying to make a condition.

if Enumber is empty in database it should return and give the new Enumber on my textbox = txtEnumber.Text = "100000".

i hope you understand my problem.

```
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Enumber FROM Employee ORDER BY Enumber DESC ", con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();

if (dr["Enumber"] == null) // Error: "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."
{
    txtEnumber.Text = "100000";
    return;
}
else 
{
    String a = dr["Enumber"].ToString();
    txtEnumber.Text = ("");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        string val = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
        int newnumber = Convert.ToInt32(val) + 1;
        a = newnumber.ToString("100000");
    }

    txtEnumber.Text = a;
}

con.Close();
```

Comment: dr.Read() returns boolean result, is false, when no data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use dr.HasRows to check whether there is data or not.

Comment: this the error i got Voilation of primary key constraint 'OK_Employee'. Connot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Employee'. the duplicate key value is (100000). the statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have *any* row in your case, you can't iterate your reader. Instead of that, you can use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) which returns `null` as an `object` if there is no data in first column of the first row since your query returns as `SELECT TOP 1..`.

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(result == null)
{
   txtEnumber.Text = "100000";
}
```

Comment: its worker thanks but i have other issue here    is tell my primary key is duplication                                          else 

        {

            String a = dr["Enumber"].ToString();

            txtEnumber.Text = ("");
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                string val = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
                int newnumber = Convert.ToInt32(val) + 1;
                a = newnumber.ToString("100000");

            }
            txtEnumber.Text = a;

        }

Comment: this the error i got Voilation of primary key constraint 'OK_Employee'. Connot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Employee'. the duplicate key value is (100000). the statement has been terminated.

Comment: @JomarlynTamargo Error message is self explanatory in my opinion. You try to insert a primary key which _already_ exist in your table. Double check your table and your values.

Comment: Gonul Enumber is set as my primary key and i check my database and table is all null Enumber data style varChar(50)

Comment: but when i click save the data from employee table is duplicated ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether there are rows first. dr.Read() returns whether the DataReader has rows, use it.
Your DataReader returns no results...

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read()) {
  // read data for first record here
}
```

If you have more than one result, use a 'while' loop.

```
while (dr.Read()) {
  // read data for each record here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read()) {
  dataTable.Load(dr);
}
```

If you have more than one result, use a 'foreach' loop.

```
foreach (DataRow Drow in datatable.Rows)
{
   // read data for each record here
}
```

Try This is Worked..

Comment: dataTable is variable for SqlDataTable?

Comment: dataTable is a object of DataTable dataTable = new DataTable() . which declared globaly..